# Issue with deleting edges in Maya 2014

Tags: 3d, maya

When I am trying to delete the edges I selected the script editor gives me the following message:

**Warning: file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya 2014/scripts/startup/cut Copy Paste.mel line 194: Nothing is selected.**

and it does not delete the edges.
 Has anybody encountered the same problem as I have?

[image]

Comment: Are your edges highlighted? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Firstly, I create a cylinder then with the cursor on the cylinder I press RMB and choose Vertex.Then, I choose the top vertices and press delete but they are not deleted.I updated my question.

Comment: To delete edges, you need to have edges selected. Same goes for faces or vertices - you always need to be in the right mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to delete the vertices, select the `Edges` from context menu and select the edge directly.

1. Right click and go to <kbd>Edges</kbd>
2. Select the edge you want
3. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to delete the top surface of the cylinder so instead of trying to delete the vertices, I chose face from the context menu and deleted the top faces that consists the top surface.Anyway, thank you for your interest!!